# Is there a way to make a HTML page to show on a WebView with support to several languages on Android?

Tags: android, html, webview, internationalization

I want to create a app that show pages HTML (with content created by me or researched from Internet), and is it possible to internationalizate the content of my pages? I need create a page HTML to each language on /res/assets?

Comment: Maybe it is not best English, but he basically wants to use WebView on one side and localized script on other side and wants to know on server side what language users is recently using. So there is not reason to close this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is unclear... You want to have a translatable app?

You can use:

```
 String locale = context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getCountry();
```

to  get the country code, and then direct to the appropriate webpage for the primary language spoken.